# Where should I start? Want to create a fictional conlang with old English, old Irish, and ancient nordic elements with unique written elements

Tags: conlang-creation

So I had an idea for a PC game that harkens somewhat to my ancestors... Imagine a fictional world blessed with angels, dragons, elves and fey and lots more, where technology is present but very rare in distribution, where most of the planet is still forested and wild. And where the setting takes place primarily on a fictional version of Ireland that is far larger than the real one. I'm Irish and Scandinavian, so I want to make a conlang that has Irish and Scandinavian elements to it, as well as viking elements. I want to make a written alphabet and language that follows what would of been the way the ancient people wrote , read and spoke "as close as possible anyway." And I have no idea where I should start. So what I am asking really is where should I begin? I have no clue.

Comment: A lot of people recommend the [Language Construction Kit](https://www.zompist.com/kit.html).